# Why is nothing showing up in my DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to initialize a `DataGridView` object. All I did was add the object to my screen without changing any properties. I have code that is run when the user selects the panel it is on. The code looks like this...

```
DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
string query = "SELECT viewfolder, status FROM Folders WHERE username = '" + Globals.usrName + "' ORDER BY viewfolder";

SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;" +
    @"AttachDbFilename=C:\Development\C-Sharp\LockItUp\Lockitup.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connect);

connect.Open();
try
{
    SqlDataAdapter dAdapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    dAdapt.Fill(tbl);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    return;
}
connect.Close();

dataGridView1.DataSource = tbl;
```

So is there any other code I have to add or properties I have to set to see the data appear on the grid? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can u able to see the column headers? Are you sure that query returns some data? because your code seems to be okay..

Comment: I don't even see column headers.

Comment: You need to set [`dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or add the columns you want in code..

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using this code:

```
void FillData()
{

    using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(
    @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;" +
@"AttachDbFilename=C:\Development\C-Sharp\LockItUp\Lockitup.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
    c.Open();

           string query = "SELECT viewfolder, status FROM Folders WHERE username = '" + Globals.usrName + "' ORDER BY viewfolder";
    using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(
        query , c))
    {
        DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
        a.Fill(tbl);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = tbl; 
    }
    }
}
```